# iOS - is it possible to record from Bluetooth mic AND receive remote control events?

Tags: ios, microphone, remote-control

I'm developing an app that listens to voice commands and the way to start/stop listening to voice commands is via remote control (Airpods or wired headset). I tried various `AVAudioSession` options with `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` and `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` and got the following result:

Whenever the default input is a bluetooth (Airpod) mic (`AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth`), the app doesn't receive remote control events. Whenever the default input is the built-in mic or a wired headset, the app does receive remote control events.

Does anyone know if it's possible to have both Bluetooth mic enabled and receive remote control events?

**I tested on iOS 11.0.1 and 11.0.3.**

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No, I actually neglected that project.